# Linked List Create Function Arbitrarily Adding Nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a function in C that should create 3 nodes for a linked list. The problem is that the function seems to be adding an extra node and I cannot spot my error. Can someone take a look at the output and code and let me know what my error is? Can the problem be with the virtual machine compile environment? I'm compiling with the following code in a virtual machine running BackTrack Linux:

> gcc link.c -o link

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DELIMITER ,

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* create()
{
    //define head pointers
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *second = NULL;
    struct node *third = NULL;

    //allocate memory
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    //setup fields
    //assign links
    head->data = 15;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 20;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 25;
    third->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int size;
    struct node *head;

    head = create();

    struct node *curr = head;

    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", curr->data);
        curr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

> 15
>   0
>   20
>   0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a linked list, curr++ does not work as it would in a standard array. The entire point of linked lists is that the data in the lists is not sequential. You cannot simply increment curr and expect it to point to the next element in the list, as malloc does not promise that sequential calls are going to return the addresses of sequential cells of memory.

What you're looking for is

```
curr = curr->next;
```

This will also require you modify your loop, however. As curr->next will be NULL one node before the last, and thus your last element will be skipped. You while condition

```
curr->next != NULL
```

should, after the above adjustment, be

```
curr != NULL
```

Further, malloc returns void pointers, and, while not necessary, I would say you should cast them to the correct pointer type.

```
 //allocate memory
head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
second = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: casting is not necessary as the assignment does it.

Comment: True, but I still prefer doing it explicitly, though it doesn't really make a difference. Just thought the void* return of malloc was worth mentioning. Edited it to include that it's not a mission critical change.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(curr)
{
    printf("%d\n", curr->data);
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

I prefer to do

```
for(curr = head; curr ; curr = curr->next)
{
    printf("%d\n", curr->data);
}
```